# My Animation Moves Across The Screen Too Fast (Graphics) (Beginner)

Tags: java, performance, animation, graphics, timer

I'm doing a project for school and I chose to recreate Duck Hunt. It's coming along pretty well so far, except for one problem, the ducks that fly out move way too fast, I have it setup as follows, the x and y are obviously the x and y coordinates of the duck that's flying and I have a loop that does y--. But like I said that goes up far too fast, and I can't use doubles with the graphics class, only an int. Heres the code I write.

(First post, I think I posted the code correctly, sorry if I didn't)

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
public class duck extends Applet implements ActionListener, MouseListener{

boolean start= true;
int x;
int y=400;
int bx=350;
int by= 285;
int counter=1;
int c=2;// (int) (Math.random()*4)+1;
boolean dog=true;
boolean dog3=false;
boolean bird=false;
public void init(){
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    //BackGround
    this.resize (612,574);
    g.drawImage(getImage(getCodeBase(), "background.png"), 0, 0, this);
    g.drawString("" +c, 10, 300);


    //Crosshair Follow
    g.drawOval (MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x-24, MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y-63, 50, 50);
    g.drawLine (MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x-24, MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y-37, MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x+24, MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y-37);
    g.drawLine (MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x, MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y-64, MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x, MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y-15);
    g.drawString ("" +MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x +" " +MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y, 100, 100);
    //this.repaint();





    //Dog
    if (dog==true)
        g.drawImage(getImage(getCodeBase(), "dog.gif"), x, y, this);
        x++;
        this.repaint();

        if (x>200){
            dog=false;
            dog3=true;
        }

        if (y<285){
            dog3=false;
        //this.repaint();
        }

        if (dog3==true){
            y=y-1;

        bird=true;
        }

        //Bird
        if (bird==true ){   



            //Start Path 1 (Right Then Left at y 100)
            if (c==1){
            g.drawImage(getImage(getCodeBase(), "birdleft.gif"), bx, by, 75, 75, this);
            bx++;
            by--;
            counter++;

            if (by>200){
                bx=bx-3;
                by--;
            }
            }
            //End Path 1

            //Start Path 2
            if (c==2){
                g.drawImage(getImage(getCodeBase(), "birdleft.gif"), bx-100, by, 75, 75, this);
                bx--;
                by--;
                counter++;

                if (by<200){
                    bx++;
                    by--;
                }
                }
            //End Path 2


        }   //End Bird True

        }   //End Graphics



public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
//this.repaint();

}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {}public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

}

}
```

Comment: Painting should should paint, it should contain as little logic as possible and NOT update the state of the UI at all. You may also like to take a look at [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Answer (score 1):

Don't animate by calling `repaint()` inside of a painting method since you have no control over the animation that way. Instead either use a Swing Timer, which should work even in an AWT program, or use your own background thread Timer, both of which you can set the rough frame rate and thereby slow down your animation.

---

**Edit**
Other problems with your code:

- You're reading in images within a painting method. Please understand that in an animation program is done a **lot**, repeatedly and out of your control. Painting must be done as fast as possible, and that anything that slows it down will slow down the perceived responsiveness of your GUI. Why keep reading in an image any time painting is done when it's much simpler and more efficient to read in the image once on program start up?
- You're using AWT a very old and clunky GUI library that was superceded by Swing over 15 years ago (which itself appears to be becoming superceded by JavaFX).
- You're creating an applet, a type of program that is hardly created or used in this day and age.
- You're Getting Mouse information by polling it in the painting method which is backwards. Instead, listen for changes with your MouseListener and MouseMotionListener.
- Don't use `if (something == true)` or `if (someOtherThing == false)` since this is prone to error. Instead simply use `if (something)` and `if (!someOtherThing)`.
- Remember to follow Java naming conventions. Your class name begins with a lower case letter when it should be capitalized. While this may seem a trivial thing to complain about, programs are written so that both humans and machines can understand them. If your code follows convention others (us and your instructors or bosses) will be able to better understand it and help you.
- Rather than drawing your own cross-hairs, consider setting the cursor (if a Swing GUI).

Comment: `MouseListener` instead of `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo()`, but I'm guessing you're getting to that ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: no actually I wasn't. I was too tired to look at the code in great detail and am in fact heading to bed. You should probably post a better answer, me thinks.

Comment: I tried to remove the repaints and if I remove the one thats not commented out the whole animation wouldn't work. And would you mind showing me how I could use the swing timer in my program.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, im pretty new to java, and whenever I get problems with my code I always just look it up and I'm always hearing about swing, but unfortunately the class (school class) at my high school is teaching us applications and applets, just the basics of how java reads things and interprets them. Im just turning in my assignments the way he wants them to be, but after I complete the class I do plan on learning the more modern approach on java.